# Jquery .on not observing new elements that are added after load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code which watches for an ajax request and then shows / hides a spinner image when the request starts / ends.

This works fine on page load. However if I update part of the page with a new ajax link, this code no longer catches the `ajax:before`. Does anyone know if there is a solution to this without having to call unbind() and then re-call the code again?

```
$("*[data-spinner]").on('ajax:before', function(e) {
    $('#' + $(e.target).data('spinner')).show();
});

$("*[data-spinner]").on('ajax:complete', function(e) {
    $('#' + $(e.target).data('spinner')).hide();
});
```

Comment: What about using delegation as thousand other duplicate topics suggest? Now just wondering if these events bubble or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('ajax:before', '*[data-spinner]', function(e) {
    $('#' + $(e.target).data('spinner')).show();
});
```

This is because jQuery binds its functions to the DOM on the pageload. If you try to bind your "data-spinner" that is not there yet jQuery will not find it and wont bind it.

However if you bind on document it can be found and we pass your '*[data-spinner]' as a 2nd parameter since its just a filter. jQuery will watch it only when you click something inside "document" so it will always be up-to-dated.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried like

```
$("body").on("'ajax:before", "*[data-spinner]", function(){
 $('#' + $(e.target).data('spinner')).show();
});

$("body").on('ajax:complete', "*[data-spinner]", function(e) {
    $('#' + $(e.target).data('spinner')).hide();
});
```

Comment: This should work especially if you are removing and creating again

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
$(document).on("ajax:before", "*[data-spinner]", function(){
    //...
});
```

Or you can use the parent element instead of document and it's better/faster, i.e.

```
$('#parent_element').on("ajax:before", "*[data-spinner]", function(){
    //...
});
```

The prototype is

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

Read more on [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Are you sure  this event propagate?

Comment: @A.Wolff, I'm not quite sure but it should because there is nothing mentioned about it.